# Tires for a Opel Vectra 2003

Tags: tires, opel

Im searching for tires for my car which is a Opel Vectra 2003 (this car is also known as Vauxhall Vectra, Holden Vectra, Chevrolet Vectra)

I cover a lot of road in a year. I do at least at least 21600 km (13422 miles) a year.

My climate is mostly wet (a lot of rain) with snow in the winter and just a couple of months of sun and hot days. Windy days are very common year round.

My daily monday thru friday is basically ~90km (56 miles) at 160-180kmph (99-112 mph) on a highway. I dont do mountains or really rough roads.

Current size is 215/55 R16 93 V (Im willing to change to 225 50 R16 93 V).

## Edit

Can someone recommend a particular type of tyre for my driving application, such as all terrain, snow, etc.?

Can someone recommend a particular compound for the tyre to have?

Are there particular size recommendations that could have benefits I am unaware of?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately, pricing/shopping assistance questions are off topic for this site because the information becomes outdated. If you'd like, bring this up at [The Pitstop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop) and we can talk about it there.

Comment: Wasnt looking for prices, more like recommendations on good tires.

Comment: Unfortunately, that falls under the ***shopping*** portion of that ...

Comment: OK, understood.

Comment: @DucatiKiller I basically striked thru extra information.

Answer (score 1):

You'd ideally want a winter tyre with good grip in wet conditions. That's exactly what you should tell the shop when you go buy your tyres. Your tyre profile is high enough and your sizes are fine.

Comment: At the speeds I go, wouldnt I completely destroy the tyre when dry? Ive always been recommended all season or summer. Winter tyres are for north climates (Russia, etc.) where it freezes almost every winter...

Comment: The V rated tyre should be good for speeds up to 240km/h. You've got 50km/h to spare, which should be more than enough to keep your tyres safe on hot days.

Answer (score 1):

Stay with the tire size on the car. There are no benefits moving to a different tire as far as speed or traction goes, especially if you are driving in a sometimes wet or snowy climate. The type of tire you are looking for would probably be a **Grand-Touring Tire**. You need one which has a [speed rating](http://www.tirerack.com/tires/tiretech/techpage.jsp?techid=35) of **S** or better. That leaves you: S (112mph), T (118mph), U (124mph), H (130mph), & V (149mph). Once you get past these, you are into the Z-rated tires, which are ultra-high performance. You could put these on your car, but you'll pay a premium for them. Realistically, you'll probably be looking at the T, U, & H values, and maybe V if the price point is good.

If you want a longer running tire (more mileage), you need to look at the UTQG rating on the tire. On Tirerack.com, they explain the [UTQG](http://www.tirerack.com/tires/tiretech/techpage.jsp?techid=48) as:

> The U.S. Department of Transportation (DOT) National Highway Traffic Safety Administration's (NHTSA) Uniform Tire Quality Grade Standards (UTQG) were originated to provide consumers with useful information to help them purchase tires based on their relative treadwear, traction and temperature capabilities.

**NOTE:** While you don't live in the US, the UTQG is still a great way to identify which tires may/may not work for you.

What this means is that the higher the UTQG, the longer lasting the tire should be. Be careful, though. The number only relates to other tires produced by a manufacturer (such as Uniroyal, BFGoodrich, etc.) and do not relate across brands. (ie: A 600 from Uniroyal does not equate to a 600 from Hankook.)

The second part of the UTQG are two letters which indicate Temperature and Treadwear. In your case, you should be looking for Temperature of A and Traction of A or AA. These values are less subjective than the number portion of the UTQG. They are specifically as follows:

```
Traction
Grades  Asphalt g-Force Concrete g-Force
AA        Above 0.54         0.41
A         Above 0.47         0.35
B         Above 0.38         0.26
C       Less Than 0.38       0.26

Temperature
Grades  Speeds in mph
A       Over 115
B       Between 100 to 115
C       Between 85 to 100
```

Whether I buy my tires online or at a store, I always **do the research** on them, to include how people review them. You'll always get people who say they hate a specific tire, but look to see exactly what they are saying and use it wisely. You can always purchase the tires you like online (in most civilized places, that is) and take them to a tire shop to have them mounted/balanced. Many online tire stores even have road hazard warranties available at a reasonable price. Personally, I don't leave home without them ... I've been burnt by the pothole *way too many times*.

Ultimately it will be up to you to choose a tire which suits you. Hopefully this will get you on your way.